# Issue with including variables in print function

Tags: python, variables, syntax-error, python-3.3

I have developed a piece of code for school and i have got to the end a run into a final problem, to finish the game i need to print off the end values of the results of the sums carried out and i am having problem including the variable names as inputted by the user, here is the code;

```
    import random

print('Welcome to the game')
char1=input('What is the fist characters name: ')
char2=input('What is the second characters name: ')
char1st=int(input('What is the strength of '+char1))
char1sk=int(input('What is the skill of '+char1))
char2st=int(input('What is the strength of '+char2))
char2sk=int(input('What is the skill of '+char2))

strmod = abs (char2st - char1st) // 5
sklmod = abs (char2sk - char1sk) //5

char1rl=random.randint(1,6)
char2rl=random.randint(1,6)

if char1rl>char2rl:
    char1nst=(char1st+strmod)
    char1nsk=(char1sk+sklmod)
    char2nsk=(char2sk-sklmod)
    char2nst=(char2st-strmod)

elif char2rl>char1rl:
    char2nst=(char2st+strmod)
    char2nsk=(char2sk+sklmod)
    char1nsk=(char1sk-sklmod)
    char1nst=(char1st-strmod)
else:
    print('both rolls where the same, no damage was given or taken')

if char1nst <= 0:
    print(str(+char1+' has died'))
elif char2nst <=0:
    print(str(+char2+' has died'))
else:
    print(+char1( ' now has a strength value of '+char1nst' and a skill value of '+char1nsk'.'))
    print(+char2( ' now has a strenght value of '+char2nst' and a skill value of '+char2nsk'.'))
```

I wrote the bit at the end in the hope that it would print the end values but i get a syntax error ?! and don't have clue why it is happening. Can someone please help me edit the last four lines so it will print in the format of:

Bob now has a strength value of 4 and a skill value of 7

I have used my method before but its not working this time so if someone could point out where i went wrong and how to amend this problem that would be great !!!!

Comment: Why do you have a `+` at the beginning of your `print`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have concatenation operators (`+`) in places where you don't need them (at the beginning of `print()` and you don't have them in places where you do need them (after the variable in `of '+char1nsk'.'`). That's what's causing the syntax error.

You might consider [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) instead of string concatenation:

```
print "%s now has a strength value of %d and a skill value of %d" % (char1, char1nst, char1nsk)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the `+` operator without anything to append:

```
print(str(+char2+' has died'))
```

You don't need the `str` nor the `+` operators there, just use multiple arguments to the `print()` function:

```
if char1nst <= 0:
    print(char1, 'has died'))
elif char2nst <=0:
    print(char2, 'has died'))
else:
    print(char1, 'now has a strength value of', char1nst, 'and a skill value of', str(char1nsk) + '.'))
    print(char2, 'now has a strength value of', char2nst, 'and a skill value of', str(char2nsk) + '.'))
```

Only in the last two lines do I use `str()` and `+` to avoid a space between the value an the `.` full stop.

You could, instead, use string formatting with the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to get a more readable string formatting option for those last 2 lines:

```
template = '{} now has a strength value of {} and a skill value of {}.'
print(template.format(char1, char1nst, char1nsk))
print(template.format(char2, char2nst, char2nsk))
```

Because the text is the same for both lines, you can re-use a template string here.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the + int the beginning of the print statements. Change it to this:

```
print char1 +' has died'

print char2 +' has died'
```

Answer (score 0):

else:
    print(char1 +' now has a strength value of '+char1nst+' and a skill value of '+char1nsk+'.')
    print(char2 +' now has a strenght value of '+char2nst+' and a skill value of '+char2nsk+'.')

Answer (score 0):

well since your using python3 why not use .format?
insert {} into your string where you want a value, then call the format() method on that string with the values you want in the correct order.

```
else:
    temp = "{} now has a strength value of {} and a skill value of {}."
    print(temp.format(char1, char1nst, char1nsk))
    print(temp.format(char2, char2nst, char2nsk))
```

cleanest soluton if you ask me.